# Representation of conditions in integer linear programming

Tags: integer-programming

How to represent in PLI the fact that inequality (1) or inequality (2) must be satisfied but not both?

- $j$ is executed before $k \rightarrow t_{ij} + p_{ij} \leq t_{ik}$ (1)
- $j$ is executed after $k \rightarrow t_{ij} \geq t_{ik} + p_{ik}$ (2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let binary decision variable $x_{jk}$ indicate whether $j$ is executed before $k$, and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
x_{jk} + x_{kj} &= 1 &&\text{for $j < k$} \\
t_{ij} + p_{ij} - t_{ik} &\le M_{ijk} (1 - x_{jk}) &&\text{for all $i$ and $j \not= k$}
\end{align}